# Oracle SQL select from multiple tables

Tags: sql, oracle

Oracle SQL select from multiple tables  and join them. Looking to find the players Full Name, Email Address, Player Number, COUNTRY_ID who are  from Australia where the player type = NEW OR EXE

> SELECT T.FIRST_NAME, T.LAST_NAME, E.EMAIL_ID, PN.PLAYER, C.COUNTRY_ID
> FROM PLAYER_TYPE T
> LEFT JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C
> ON T.PLAYER_ID = C.PLAYER_ID
> RIGHT JOIN PLAYER_CONTACT C
> ON P.CONTACT_ID = C.CONTACT_ID
> AND C.COUNTRY_CODE='AUS'
> AND T.PLAYER_TYPE = 'NEW' OR 'EXE'

Below is the expected output

```
    MARK CLARKSON  dfgh@gmail.com  480 04  
   CATH SPEARS tygh@yahoo.com 481 04
   FESS LOPEZ fgvhb@yandex.com 482 04
   FEXS LOPEZ   byvg@google.com 483 04
   EOVA SMITH  ghjkjh@sdf.com 493 04
```

Here is the SQL fiddle

https://dbfiddle.uk/LPzlOcwB

Comment: Hi - you haven’t actually asked a question. What’s the issue with your SQL?

Comment: A few problems with that SQL. You cannot write `T.PLAYER_TYPE = 'NEW' OR 'EXE'`, you probably want `T.PLAYER_TYPE IN ('NEW', 'EXE')`. You have logic using a table with alias `P` but don't actually join a table with that alias, your probably want to join all of your tables. You have two tables aliased `C`, you need to give them different names. I'm also skeptical of your left/right joins (for this sample data, I think you can just use inner joins).

Comment: Here's a version that works with your Fiddle, but you'll want to understand it, not just copy it. https://dbfiddle.uk/l_xyuLL_

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`T.PLAYER_TYPE = 'NEW' OR 'EXE'` is not valid syntax and you can use `INNER JOIN` rather then an `OUTER JOIN` and need to join all the tables rather than joining `player_contact` twice.

Like this:

```sql
SELECT t.first_name || ' ' || t.last_name AS full_name,
       e.email_id,
       p.player_number,
       p.country_id
FROM   playertype t
       INNER JOIN player p
       ON (p.player_id = t.player_id)
       INNER JOIN country_table c
       ON (p.country_id = c.country_id)
       INNER JOIN player_contact pc
       ON (p.player_id = pc.player_id)
       INNER JOIN contact_email e
       ON (pc.contact_id = e.contact_id)
WHERE  player_type IN ('NEW', 'EXE')
AND    c.country_name = 'AUSTRALIA'
```

Which, for your sample data, outputs:

| FULL_NAME | EMAIL_ID | PLAYER_NUMBER | COUNTRY_ID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| MARK CLARKSON | dfgh@gmail.com | 480 | 04 |
| CATH SPEARS | tygh@yahoo.com | 481 | 04 |
| FESS LOPEZ | fgvhb@yandex.com | 482 | 04 |
| FEXS LOPEZ | byvg@google.com | 483 | 04 |
| EOVA SMITH | ghjkjh@sdf.com | 493 | 04 |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/wLwcC963)